# Optimize multiple images with different resolution

Tags: photo

I have 10 logo images of some companies but some of them are horizontal and some of them are vertical.

I need to optimize them for the carousel so they should look optimized...how do you solve this problem?

Now it looks like this:

[image]

Sebastian Loder is too high....

Comment: a tool for what? to make an horizontal image look vertical?

Comment: No...just to somehow optimize them so the pictures look like they are about the same size. I think the problem is with the white/transparent part of photo....on some photos the logo is in the middle and there is plenty of space around and on some images the logo is from margin to margin...no free space and if you resize those images; on one image the logo is too small and on the other too big, even though they have the exact same resolution!!!

Comment: This question is way too broad. I mean, you are asking how to make minor edits with picture. Are you sure that you can turn on the computer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution #1 Manual editing pictures**

try editing the picture with photoshop or [gimp(freeware)](http://www.gimp24.de/). When you transform them into png and make the white background transparent and then optimize the hight/width of the picture you might get the solutiont you need.
*Search for youtube tutorials*

**Solution #2 Use CSS to display the pictures in a different way**

you could also show your pictures in your website in a way, that you set the [hight/width](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_dimension.asp) of the pictures with CSS.
Adding a [vertical-align](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_vertical-align.asp) you might also get to a different solution without editing the images yourself which might look different, but it should also fit your purpose.

Comment: solution #1b. Compress images so they load faster.